# How do i find percentage change between consecutive numbers?

Tags: python, math

so I'm trying to find the percentage change between two consecutive numbers such as percentage change between 2367700 and 2113425 for the first loop. 2113425 and 2107145 for the second loop etc. Currently, the code isn't working and is giving me an error saying 'int' object is not subscriptable. Thank you for the help.

```
perchange = [2367700,2113425,2107145,2125476,2232400,2325301,2550833,2761819,2893455,3123843]
def percentagechange(old,new):
   return((float(new)-old)/abs(old)*100)
for idx,val in enumerate(perchange):
   pc = percentagechange(val[idx], val[idx+1])
   print(pc)
```

Comment: val[idx] - here your idx is the index of the val object in the perchange list. You don't need to use it as val[idx], you just need to use val instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `enumerate()`

Also, you need to index the list, not the integer. When you are doing `val[idx]`, `val` is an integer, so you get an error

```
perchange = [2367700,2113425,2107145,2125476,2232400,2325301,2550833,2761819,2893455,3123843]
def percentagechange(old,new):
    return((float(new)-old)/abs(old)*100)
for idx in range(len(perchange)-1):
    pc = percentagechange(perchange[idx], perchange[idx+1])
    print(pc)
```

Comment: why is it necessary to include the -1 in range(len(perchange)-1):

Comment: Because if I don't, and at the last element, I do ```idx+1```, I'll get an index error @twicefanboy6231

Comment: I see, understood. Thank you very much @Sujay

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
perchange = [2367700,2113425,2107145,2125476,2232400,2325301,2550833,2761819,2893455,3123843]
pc = [100 * y / x for x,y in zip(perchange, perchange[1:])]
print(pc)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
perchange = [2367700,2113425,2107145,2125476,2232400,2325301,2550833,2761819,2893455,3123843]

percentagechange = [0]
for i in range(1, len(perchange)):
    percentagechange.append(round((abs(perchange[i]-perchange[i-1]) / perchange[i-1]) * 100, 2))
print(percentagechange)
```

Output:

```
[0, 10.74, 0.3, 0.87, 5.03, 4.16, 9.7, 8.27, 4.77, 7.96]
```